# Angular Material mat-select - Showing count number along with the first selected value in multiple selection

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

In mat-select multiple selections, all the selected values are displayed in the select field. I want only the first selected value along with +1 or +2 etc if more than one value is selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<mat-select-trigger>` to customize the displayed output of selected value(s).

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
  <mat-select-trigger>
    {{toppings.value ? toppings.value[0] : ''}}
    <span *ngIf="toppings.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
      +{{toppings.value.length - 1}}
    </span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
.example-additional-selection {
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxjisc?file=src/app/select-custom-trigger-example.html)

---

### References

[Select | Angular Material (Section: Select with custom trigger text)](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)